# how to update quantity in shopping cart in flask?

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I'm working on a shopping cart and I'm coding from scratch to try to figure out how it actually works.  I ran into a hiccup. the items in the shopping cart are retrieved from MySQL database and are displayed in a table on a website. I want the user to change the quantity automatically when they select the quantity.

I've tried adding  tag around and inside the option tag but it does nothing. I also tried adding it around the select tag but once i click on the element the link is run. I came across something like this: onchange="location = this.value;" but I don't know how to implement it.

```
html select code.
<select id="quantity" name="quantity" class="form-control" style="background-color:white ; border-color:white">
    {% for number in quantity_data %}
    <option value="{{ number.quantity }}"><a href="/confirm_cart">{{ number.quantity }}</a></option>
    <!--<input name="description" type="text" placeholder="Enter description..." class="form-control">-->
    {% endfor %}
</select>

flask code - app.py
if request.method == 'POST':
    customer_name = request.form['customer_name']
    item = request.form['item_']
    cost = request.form['cost']
    quantity = request.form['quantity']

        con = pymysql.connect("localhost", "root", "", "sampledb")
        # update main database
        cursor = con.cursor()
        sql = "UPDATE `shopping_cart_tbl` " \
              "SET `customer_name`=%s, `item`=%s, `cost`=%s, `quantity`=%s " \
              "WHERE `customer_name`=%s"

        cursor.execute(sql, (customer_name, item, cost, quantity, session['userkey']))
        con.commit()
```

Simply put, i want the select options to act as a link. I already have the update database SQL code. Here's the code

Comment: Two things, if I understand correctly; first, you're not updating any quantity after the insert into the table (either you need to update a value in the session or re-count the items after insert) and secondly, you're not feeding back to the template which probably requires AJAX/JQuery to update that value alone rather than refresh the page.

Comment: in the database the column quantity already has a default 1. when the user selects an option in the drop-down menu in the shopping cart page, it should be updated by running a route that way the change is recorded.. I'm updating in the database. I'm only using session to keep track of the logged in user's cart items so that they are displayed on the shopping cart table. You can replace session['userkey'] with 'peter' pr someone's name.

Comment: Thats not what I'm saying. You update it in the database - fine - But why should that automatically update the front end without you actually doing it? You're not reloading anything on the front end.

Comment: i see what you're saying. I hadn't gotten to that point yet honestly. My first concern was updating the DB. I hadn't considered retrieving the database value and displaying it at the front end. IAny suggestion for doing both